# Find issues as of certain date in JIRA

Tags: filtering, jira

I am not sure if this is possible - I would like to know which issues were in which state on certain date. I tried but did not find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: To make it clear, I would like to see status of the project e.g. a week ago, such as:

```
PROJECT=A AND issueType=Bug ON 2015/04/04 //something like that
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can** **!!**

Jira has advanced search feature,where you can provide different query and you can also get all bugs for one or more projects at particular data.
For more details go through

> To get  bugs created,resolved or updated on  particular date there are custom fields `created at` , `resolved at` and `updated at` and then you need pass date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

[Reference] http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/jql-the-most-flexible-way-to-search-jira-14/

Comment: Thanks, well I read that and it does not really answer whether I can see the search result on a specific date (I know I can filter if something changed, I would just need something like PROJECT=A AND ISSUE=B ON 2015/01/01

Comment: Jira doesn't store history of bugs,eg.If you want status of `bug X` which is closed today and what you want is status of `bug X` yesterday so according to you that status should be other than closed.Jira didn't manage Such history of bugs.Every information will be live.